# How to embed an <a href> tag (which includes ") into a Field in InfoPath 2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, infopath

I want my View of a SharePoint InfoPath list field URL to show JUST a description, (e.g. an ID value of "23501") in the column exposed.  Right now if I use a Text field it shows the entire URL and is clickable. If I use InfoPath Hyperlink field, it is exposed as just the description but is NOT clickable.  Both options are shown below.  How can I make it expose a Clickable ID only?

[image]

Comment: FYI - using Designer Workflow to set the text field to the <a href="... syntax  didn't work. it set the field but SharePoint parsed it as TEXT (<a href=")<LINK AND DESCRIPTION HERE>(</a>).

Answer (score 1):

If you have the flexibility of putting files in the 14 hive, you can use a [Computed Field](http://www.threewill.com/2012/07/computed-fields-in-sp-2010/) to do this.  A Computed Field can take values from an field in the list and create markup around it using XSLT.  A better way is using Display Templates, but that is SharePoint 2013.

Comment: can you expand or point me to where instructions are to do this??

Comment: Did you try the link I provided above?  http://www.threewill.com/2012/07/computed-fields-in-sp-2010/

Comment: oh sorry didn't 'see' it! will try, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In a workflow, you can build a dynamic string of the URL and description in this format: URL, Description. The comma space is important. Then update a hyperlink field with that dynamic string variable and you should get your result.

Comment: this didn't work. it only shows as a description field in the Summary view of the list library.  it parses only when the form is opened, correctly.

Comment: I've used this method before without issue, will look at it again